# Entity Manager JPA persist does insert data in created table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, entitymanager, persist

java correctly connects to the database via wildfly and creates the table in the database. With the ManagerCount I want to insert test data to the database. 
 '
    package hm.edu.chatServer.service;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity // markiert Klasse als Entität
public class CountProcess implements Serializable {  

    @Id //  Primary Key Attribut
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;

    @Column(name="Benutzername")
    private String userName;


    @Column(name="numberOfReceivedConfirms")
    private int numberOfReceivedConfirms;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getNumberOfReceivedConfirms() {
        return numberOfReceivedConfirms;
    }

    public void setNumberOfReceivedConfirms(int numberOfReceivedConfirms) {
        this.numberOfReceivedConfirms = numberOfReceivedConfirms;
    }
}
'
```

here my persistence.xml:

```
    '
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="counttabelle" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/countDS</jta-data-source>
      <class>hm.edu.chatServer.service.CountProcess</class>
      <properties>
           <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/count?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"></property>
         <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="ManagerCount"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/> 
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
        }
    }
    '
```

here my ManagerCount.java:
    '
    package hm.edu.chatServer.service;

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless  
public class ManagerCount {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="counttabelle")
    private EntityManager emc;

    public CountProcess create(CountProcess CountProcess){
        emc.persist(CountProcess);

        return CountProcess;
    }
}
'
```

What do I have to do when I want to insert test data into the created tables?

Comment: you need to call persist, and then commit the transaction. And if you have a problem you look in the log of your chosen JPA provider ...

Comment: Thank you! so like this?

Comment: ' public CountProcess save(CountProcess countProcess){ //Um Entität "count" aus Klasse "CountProcess" in DB zu speichern    create oder save
     emc.getTransaction().begin();
     emc.persist(countProcess);
     emc.getTransaction().commit();
  
  return countProcess;'

Comment: sry here the right:

Comment: public CountProcess save(CountProcess countProcess){
     emc.getTransaction().begin();
     emc.persist(countProcess);
     emc.getTransaction().commit();
  
  return countProcess;

Comment: yes, like that if using Local Transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
public CountProcess create(CountProcess CountProcess){
        emc.persist(CountProcess);
        emc.getTransaction().commit();
        emc.close();
        return CountProcess;
    }
```

You can test in your **servlet** by creation an object of type **CountProcess** an populate it with your test data, then call your create method from an instance of **ManagerCount**  class

Comment: Ok Thank you! My Problem is now how I can insert Test data to see if it works?

Comment: create a CountProcess object,use your setters and then call your create methode.

Comment: Thanks do I have to put the CountProcess object with the setters in my ManagerCount.java? And where do I have to call my create methode?